# Yet another question about p-value interpretation

Tags: p-value

I'm almost positive I'm going to be marked for duplicate, but I really *really* just need this sorted out once and for all with a simple example.

I don't understand how a small p-value is evidence *against* the null hypothesis.

Take a simple example: testing if a coin is fair. This is modeled with a binomial distribution with $n$ fixed (the number of times we flip the coin) and parameter $p$. The null hypothesis $H_0$ is $p = 0.5$.

Now, let our test statistic be $D = |X - np|$, where $X$ is the number of heads in the sample (binomially distributed). The p-value is defined as $p = P(D \ge d\ |\ H_0)$, where $d$ is our observed value of the statistic.

Lets say we find, initially, for $100$ tosses that $60$ heads occurred. So $d = 10$. Then $p = P(D\ge 10\ |\ H_0)$.

Here begins my interpretation:

**Then a small p-value means its unlikely for D to be greater than 10, assuming our hypothesis is true.**

This means, its **more likely** for $D \le 10$, which is "near" $0$. That means that the sample $X$ is **very likely close to a binomial distribution with p=.5**.

That's my innterpretation of it, for which I can't find anything wrong. **Why, then, does a small p-value indicate strong evidence *against* the hypothesis?**

That makes zero sense to me. If $p$ is small, then our test statistic is close to zero, meaning our model is mostly likely correct! Why on Earth is that evidence *against* $H_0$, that's completely in support of it! Please, **what is wrong with this?** I can't for the life of me tell.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=votes for more about this subject.

Comment: @whuber I have looked at the question you marked mine as a "duplicate" of, but I have already read it and it does _not_ answer my question. In fact, the accepted answer only serves to _enforce_ my faulty interpretation.

Comment: "If p is small, then our test statistic is close to zero, meaning our model is mostly likely correct!"  This is the source of your mistake.  If n is close to 50 then the p-value will be close to 50%.  If $D\ge{10}$ then it is far away and the p-value is small.  The p-value on a two tailed test will be 5.6% at $D=\pm{10}$.

Comment: So in this _specific_ example, the p-value isn't actually small, because our sample isn't actually statistically "close" to the hypothesized model?

Comment: There are many good answers to the duplicate that address your questions.  Whether or not you consider my answer there to be any good, I discuss these issues *thoroughly* and *explicitly* in that answer.

Comment: @whuber I didn't realize that one was yours. To be fair I stopped near the top because it's a long read, and I have a short millennial attention span.

Comment: That's _millennial_ to non-millennials....

Comment: Case in point, couldn't even be bothered to look up the correct spelling.

Comment: (+1) for cando[u]r.